# Where did the money go?

Tags: money

In very wealthy PSEland, the hourly rate is £1,000. A man works for 1,000 hours and earns £1,000,000. Nice going!

The next year, the government of PSEland decided to raise his wages by 10%, so to earn his million, he only worked for 909.090909 hours, which is 91% of 1000 hours (roughly!).

> So a 10% increase in wages results in a 9% decrease in worked hours.

**Where did the 1% go?**

Comment: The 1% of what?

Comment: a 10% increase in wages should result in a 10% decrease in worked hours, @noedne

Comment: I get that they look like the same number, but why would someone expect that to be true?

Comment: @noedne; that's for me to know and for you to find out! :)

Comment: Percentages confuse people a lot, I guess

Comment: This question has a [distinct flavour](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/169:_Words_that_End_in_GRY) to it that I don't very much like. Contrast with this question: "He got a 200% raise, why isn't he working negative 1000 hours?"

Comment: @Bass; I do have a definite answer in mind though and it's not a trick, and what's wrong with OGRY - like an ogre? (I mean ogre-like).

Comment: This reminds me of those goofy probability questions that ask: why does probability work like this? To which the answer is, why shouldn't it.

Comment: Did the 1% move to a different state to avoid a tax hike?  :-)

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: **that’s not how percentages work.**

Long answer:

> A $p\%$ increase in a value *followed by* a $p\%$ decrease does not give us back our original value. That’s because we’re taking the $p\%$ decrease of the increased value, so our discount is slightly more than if we took the discount of the original amount. Thus, if we wanted to get back to our original value, we need to take a percentage decrease that’s *lower* than $p\%.$
>
>  Mathematically speaking, if we let $P = \frac{p}{100},$ then we’re trying to find $d$ such that $(1 + P)(1 - d) = 1.$ The solution is $d = \frac{P}{1 + P},$ which is less than $P.$

Answer (score 0):

The question

> doesn't make sense.   You have a formula  r x h = 1 M, where r = h = 1000. Therefore 1.1r x 1/1.1h = 1M and 1/1.1 = .9090909...

in general

> whatever increase (1+r) of salary is accompanied by a decrease of 1/(1+r) of hours.